# Is this a good way to pass variables between asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's the first time I'm passing variables between two pages in my asp.net project. 
It works, but I'm wondering if it is a good way to do it? Is it secure? Is there a better way?
The reason why I ask is that I've have learned never to use concatenation in sql, but instead use parameters (which I always do from now on). Is there a similar risk in this case?

In web page1:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        string date = txtDate.Text;
        string time = txtTime.Text;
        string name = txtName.Text;

        string url = "~/change.aspx?newemail="+mail+"&newdate="+date+"&newtime="+time+"&newname="+name+"";
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

In web page2:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String email = Request.QueryString["newemail"];
        String date = Request.QueryString["newdate"];
        String time = Request.QueryString["newtime"];
        String name = Request.QueryString["newname];
        TextBox1.Text = email;
        TextBox2.Text = date;
        TextBox3.Text = time;
        TextBox4.Text = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if it is a good way to do it?

Not really. You need to url encode the values because if they contain special characters the receiving page will not parse them correctly:

```
string url = "~/change.aspx?" + 
"newemail=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mail) + 
"&newdate=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(date) + 
"&newtime=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(time) + 
"&newname=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name);
```

> Is it secure?

No, not at all. Anyone could send a request to your target page with whatever values he feels good for him.

> Is there a better way?

That would depend on your specific requirements and whether the information you are transmitting is sensitive or not. If it is sensitive information, then you might consider storing the values on the server instead of passing them as query string parameters. For example you could use the ASP.NET Session for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added HttpUtility.UrlEncode as you suggested. I will consider using Session later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Is it secure? No, of course not, the values are on the query string which gets sent to the browser. If you want to keep it secure put the values in session on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You are using QueryString Way to pass variables from one page to another page.its not a problem if the parameters are not secure like you cant pass secure info(Sensitive Information) like passwords,any important ids...

if you want to handle with secure parameters(Sensitive Information) you can use Sessions,Cookies..

In your case you are passing names.i hope it doesnt create any problems because this are not secure parameters(Sensitive info).even though if you feel any security risks you can use encryption  and decryption concepts like encrypt your parameter name and pass it with url and then decrypt  that parameter where you want to use.

Refer :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8055/Transferring-page-values-to-another-page

For better understanding about passing variables from one page to another page

Comment: I'm not passing very sensitive information like passwords or id:s, but I will consider using Sessions. I will read your links.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for you help!
I have now changed it to Sessions. My code now looks like this:

In web page1:

```
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        string date = txtDate.Text;
        string time = txtTime.Text;
        string name = txtName.Text;

        Session["email"] = email;
        Session["date"] = date;
        Session["time"] = time;
        Session["name"] = name;

        Response.Redirect("~/change.aspx");
```

In web page2:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        string email = (string)(Session["email"]);
        string date = (string)(Session["date"]);
        string time = (string)(Session["time"]);
        string name = (string)(Session["name"]);

        TextBox1.Text = email;
        TextBox2.Text = date;
        TextBox3.Text = time;
        TextBox4.Text = name;
    }
```